# Visual Studios Web Setup Project

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-setup-project

I'm trying to create an installer for an ASP.NET MVC Application. The installer will deploy the site to a user's local IIS and set up connection to database and create database and tables if it doesn't exist.

I'm using the Web Setup Project for this. So far I was able to create the installer that will deploy the site to the IIS. Now I'm looking for a way to set the connections and create database. Are there any sources or recommendations on how to do this?

I also looked at the WiX Toolset for this and couldn't really figure out how to do it. Sources for either one would help

Comment: If it is more common to write a PowerShell script to configure IIS, then call it from any installer technology you like.

Comment: @LexLi assume I'm a big novice and have no clue what that means. Sorry

Comment: Stack Overflow is not for tutorials. Use a search engine to study IIS's PowerShell cmdlets and so on.